# Probability of two buyers service time

Tags: probability

I have a geometric distribution question and I don't know how exactly it should be solved and how graph should look like.

The question is:

> Serving one person takes from $8$ to $22$ minutes time. What's the probability that two buyers serving time will be from $23$ to $32$ minutes?

The problem is that I don't know how to draw graph for this question.

Thanks for any help you could give me!

Comment: Why do you assume geometric distribution for serving time?

Comment: Because I need graph to solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

I am going to assume that the service time are uniformly distributed between $8$ and $22$ for a single person and the service time for both customers are independent.

Draw the square region $\{(x,y): 8 \le x\le 22, 8 \le y \le 22\}.$

Now compute the proportion of region that satisfy $$23 \le x+y \le 32.$$

Comment: The independence assumption doesn’t seem reasonable though. This information should be in the question.